# Why don't two variables referencing the same object change when one of them does?

Tags: java, string

**Question**

The below code show that when affecting an array to an another one, the two arrays becomes depending to each others.

```
int tab [] = {1,2,3};

int tab2 [] = tab;

tab2[0] = 5;

System.out.print(tab[0]); // 5
```

I want to know why this isn't the same with the type `String`, since if we had the following :

```
String ch1 = "hello";

String ch2 = ch1;

ch2 = "hi";

System.out.print(ch1); // hello
```

The two variables `ch1` and `ch2` are referencing the same string, so changing one will affect the other.

Comment: The two variables are clearly not referencing the same string, as your snippet demonstrates.

Comment: In the first example you're modifying the value of something referenced by two variables. In the second example you're changing the reference of `ch2`.

Comment: changing String in Java is not possible, String provides immutable objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think like this.

Both array and String operate based on Addresses.

When you say `arr1 = arr2`, you are telling that `arr1` is going to be pointing to same address location as `arr2`.

With strings, "XYZ" is also a string, which contains an address location. when you say `str1 = str2`, `str1` will be pointing to same address as `str2`. But when you say `str1 = "XYZ"`, "XYZ" is another object which is stored at a different address. So, str1 will be reassigned to the new address.

Even with arrays, if you say `arr1 = arr3`, `arr2` won't be changing. `arr1` will be repointed to a new address pointed by `arr3`. But when you say `arr1[0]`, you are actually trying to change the value stored in location, so it will also influence `arr2` or `arr3` depending on which assignment is latest.

Comment: After analysing the situation i concluded the same thing that you explained. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

When you use

```
int tab2 [] = tab;
```

then `tab2` is a *reference* to the same array. Changing the value of `tab2[0]` meaning you change a value inside the data structure that both `tab` and `tab2` are pointing at.

Using

```
ch2 = "hi";
```

create a new instance of `String`, it does not change the object that `ch2` was referring to before.

Comment: Please don't bring the immutability of `String` into this, it's irrelevant. The same concept applies to any type. This issue is a re-assignment of the variable.

Comment: Yeah, immutability is not the cause. It works the same way even for mutable objects.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that is correct, i removed it.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't changing the `String` itself, you are just setting another value for `ch2` **reference**, so it **refers** to a new `String` object, `ch1` still refers to the old `String` object.

To make your array code similar to the string code, you need to change it a bit

```
 int tab [] = {1,2,3};

int tab2 [] = tab;

tab2 = new int[]{5,6,7};

System.out.print(tab[0]); // 1
```

Comment: The `System.out.println` will actually print 1, I would get rid of that comment at the end.

Comment: I think he means tab2[0]

Comment: @user3078643 no it was `tab[0]` I just made a mistake with the comment, it would be 1, not 5 because tab is still the original array.

Comment: i see, thanks for the answer.